# Bootstrap Strapi with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, strapi

I am getting the following error and cannot figure out, what's wrong:

I have read the documentation carefully, and made a docker-compose.yml based on an example found at https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker/blob/master/examples/mysql/docker-compose.yml

```
api_1       | Using strapi 3.0.0-beta.19.3
api_1       | No project found at /srv/app. Creating a new strapi project
api_1       | Creating a new Strapi application at /srv/app.
api_1       |
api_1       | ⛔️ You can only create a Strapi app in an empty directory.
api_1       | Make sure /srv/app is empty.
```

That is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.4"

services:
  api:
    depends_on:
      - database

    image: strapi/strapi

    container_name: core_api

    environment:
      #APP_NAME: wlc-core
      DATABASE_CLIENT: mysql
      DATABASE_HOST: database
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      DATABASE_NAME: development
      DATABASE_USERNAME: development
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: development
      DATABASE_SSL: "false"

    ports:
      - 1337:1337

    volumes:
      - ./services/api/api:/srv/app/api
      - ./services/api/config:/srv/app/config
      - ./services/api/extensions:/srv/app/extensions
      - ./services/api/public:/srv/app/public

  database:
    image: mariadb:10.4.4-bionic

    container_name: core_database

    volumes:
      - ./services/database/data:/var/lib/mysql

    ports:
      - 3306:3306

    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: development
      MYSQL_DATABASE: development
      MYSQL_USER: development
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: development
```

I got that container running once. But since then it cannot be run anymore.
I removed the stopped container, that was created before building a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You are configuring the wrong volumes.
As stated in the Github link you provided, the only volume you need to mount in `core_api` is the following:

```
volumes:
    - ./app:/srv/app
```

Or in your case:

```
volumes:
    - ./services/api:/srv/api
```

The app directory contains the whole application (APIs, models, configurations, etc...). so you don't need to mount every subdirectory, only the top-level one.

Comment: I already thought about that as reason. But even if I do it like you and the example say, the same happens. BTW I did bind mount every relevant folder, because I don't want to have node_modules reflected on the host, because I believe this has impact on performance and it is not neccessary. If I need the node_modules for e.g. devDependencies and my vs-code, I can still run `yarn` on my host machine. Also some of the dependencies won't work in different environments (host: mac, container: linux)

Comment: When you tried to mount only the top-level directory, did you deleted the containers right before? Strapi installation will fail if there are already files into the target directory (which is the case after your first try). I tried your docker-compose.yml with the modified lines and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I did delete all containers before I tried the "top-leve-way". It is wierd! Today I tried again, and it worked. Again after a `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` it didn't work again. But isnt it strange, that it's saying "No project found at /srv/app. Creating a new strapi project"?? So there cannot be an issue with wrong bind mounts containing data to provoke the next error. (See my error description again).